# How to make web using style.css?

Tags: css

I've been uploaded my web in server, but if I save my page from browser and while I open the web, style.css is not active... how to active style.css into my web?
I used this,

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>`

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

Comment: You know what is meaning ../style.css means its in parent folder of current folder

Comment: Where are your html file and style.css file ?

Answer (score 2):

see this and check your path

**CASE 1**

```
|-style.css     
|-index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

**CASE 2**

```
|-style.css     
|-folder
        |-index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

**CASE 3**

```
|-css 
      |-style.css       
|-folder
        |-index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox extension FireBug to debug code and define problems
https://www.getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

If this doesn't work, tell us your folder structure for your stylesheet.